# What happens to LPs if liquidity of uniswap extinguish?

Tags: uniswap, decentralized-exchange

I have a doubt that if an LP provided its tokens to the uniswap pool but someone else in the world swapped and took all of the tokens from the pool so how can he/she withdraw its tokens? Will it get back the tokens? or has to wait for some time till someone else has added some liquidity?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If an LP provided its tokens to the uniswap pool but someone else in the world swapped and took all of the tokens from the pool, then the LP will stuck with tokens he or she can't sell and experience impermanent loss. This is what usually happens with rug pulls, but it can also happen naturally if the market doesn't provide enough liquidity.

See: https://www.coindesk.com/learn/2021/07/13/defi-lending-3-major-risks-to-know/